# load templates from database in dajngo

Tags: django, templates, model

I am working on a project where some templates are stored as part of a 'theme' in the database. Because of this, I'm not able to leverage a lot of Django's nice template rendering functionality immediately, i tried using dajngo-dbtemplates and added template to database but i couldn't find a way how to render those templates to let users to select their choice of template.basically i am working on a project for digitcards that let user to choose their choice of template and shows their details onto it

Comment: There is nothing that stops you to save templates in database and rendering them out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#rendering-a-context

Comment: could you please refer to some project or example instead of django doucmentations , this is so confusing